# Cannot transfer data to Linux VM through FileZilla

Tags: linux, centos, filezilla

I want to transfer from my local computer to my Linux (CentOs) VM through FileZilla. The file should be in this path in my Linux VM: `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors. But when I try to upload the file into this path, then this failure occurs

```
Error:  /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/test.docx: open for write: permission denied
Error:  File transfer failed
```

Can someone tell me where is my mistake? Please bear with me, because I am new to Linux.

Comment: Make sure you have permission to write into the destination directory.

Comment: It looks like a normal permission issue or it can be selinux. Which kind of session is it (ftp/SFTP/scp) and hat is the Backend (sshd or another server)? Which user you use?

Comment: I changed permission like this and it works: ```sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors```. Is this the right way?

Comment: No, that's not the right way. Using 777 as file/directory mode should not be used, it would be better to see what owner and group is set on the directory. Then see if your user can be member of that group and set mode `g+w` on the directory you need access to. If owner and group are both set to `root` see if it is feasible to use another group (one where your user is member of or even a new one). I would try to avoid write/execute access for `other` where I can.